# Soma de caracter em Portugol

Tags: visualg, portugol

A soma de duas variáveis do tipo caracter, pode ser considerada uma concatenação ?

Answer (score 1):

A "soma" de duas variáveis pode sim ser considerada uma concatenação, porém utiliza-se a expressão "soma" quando falamos em somar, em operações matemáticas. O sinal de "+" entre variáveis que são strings é chamado de concatenação.

> Concatenar significa ligar, unir de modo lógico e homogêneo; manter ligação ou conexão entre: concatenava teorias; seu argumento concatena com a perspectiva da revista; as ideias se concatenaram naquela aula.

**Exemplo de concatenação de strings em portugol:**

```
inicio
     string nome, sobrenome, resultado;
     escreva ("Digite o primeiro nome: ");
     leia nome;  
     escreva ("Digite o segundo nome: ");
     leia sobrenome;
     resultado = nome + sobrenome;
     escreva ("Seu nome completo é: " resultado);
fim
```

O resultado será a leitura de "nome" + "sobrenome", que nesse caso seria o primeiro e segundo nome.

**Saída:**

> Digite o primeiro nome: **Victor**
>
> Digite o segundo nome: **Hugo**
>
> Seu nome completo é: **Victor Hugo**

Answer (score -2):

Sim, concatenação, usado no contexto de computação é realmente o processo de "juntar" strings, como pode ser visto no Wiki: [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)